# Change derived data location in Xcode

Tags: xcode, deriveddata

The location of my derived data folder differs between Xcode and Finder.

How do I change Xcode's path to match my Finder path?

MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1, MacBook Air M1, 8GB

Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit the folder that is used by Xcode for the derived data:

"Xcode" -> "Settings..." -> "Locations"

There's a "Derived Data:" drop down menu, where you can pick "Custom" and pick the desired folder.